# Repetição de texto e data em dataframe no R

Tags: r

[image: Dúvida:]

Olá, pessoal!

Estou com uma base de dado em Excel e preciso fazer sua manipulação no R. Só que estou com um problema e não sei como resolvê-lo. Conforme segue na imagem, tenho a coluna Mês e Variável e tenho que repetir o texto nos valores faltantes (NA), preencher a coluna Mês com Janeiro 2000 até Fevereiro 2000, de Fevereiro 2000 até Março 2000 e assim por diante.
Na coluna Variável, eu teria que repetir o texto "Índice de volume..." nos NAs até o "índice de receita" e após repetir o "Índice de receita...". Se alguém souber algum caminho para resolver essas questões, ficarei muito agradecido!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Oi Bruno! A tua pergunta terá mais chance de ter uma boa resposta se os teus dados podem ser replicados por outras pessoas. Podes usar `dput()` sobre teus dados (`dput(dados)`) ou parte deles (algumas linhas ou únicamente as colunas que desejas modificar) para ajudar as pessoas que podem te ajudar. Dá uma olhada nesse post sobre o procedimento para perguntar em stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Oi Jose! Obrigado pela dica, vou tentar melhorar

Answer (score 4):

Consegui resolver o problema em questão, espero que a resposta junto da pergunta possa ajudar alguém.
Para replicar as observações nos `"NA"`, utilizei a função `fill` do pacote `tidyr`. Ficou da seguinte forma:

```
meus_dados = read_excel("local do arquivo excel") %>% fill(Mês, .direction = "down")
```

A função ".direction = "down" preenche os espaços NA com a última observações disponível na coluna.